# TypeScript allow for optional arguments - overloading methods

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this method signature on a class:

```
lock(key: string, opts: any, cb?: LMClientLockCallBack): void;
```

if a user uses it like so:

```
lock('foo', null, (err,val) => {

});
```

they will get the right typings. However, if they omit the options argument and do this:

```
lock('foo', (err,val) => {

});
```

then `tsc` sees the callback function as type `any`, just like this:

[image]

Is there any way to allow users to avoid passing an empty object or null as the second argument, and shift the callback over?

I tried overloading the method, into two definitions:

```
  lock(key: string, cb: LMClientLockCallBack, n?: LMClientLockCallBack) : void;

  lock(key: string, opts: any, cb?: LMClientLockCallBack) { ... }
```

but it still doesn't compile, there are new problems:

[image]

and if I try this:

```
  lock(key: string, cb: LMClientLockCallBack) : void;

  lock(key: string, opts: any, cb?: LMClientLockCallBack) { ... }
```

I get this:

[image]

Surely there must be a solution to this one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When overloading the method in TypeScript, the implementation doesn't count as one of overloads. You should thus create three function definitions: two ones for different overloads, as you've already done, and the third - with optional argument and real implementation, which is in your code erroneously connected to the second overload definition. So you'll have:

```
lock(key: string, cb: LMClientLockCallBack) : void;
lock(key: string, opts: any, cb: LMClientLockCallBack): void;

lock(key: string, opts: any, cb?: LMClientLockCallBack) { ... }
```

So, if the second argument is a callback - user will get the first overload typings, if it is anything else, but the third argument is a callback - the second overload typings. But in both cases they will call the same implementation, just like it would be in pure JavaScript.

Comment: `the implementation doesn't count as one of overloads.` that single statement saved my day.....